# Error Capturing specific bounds

Tags: python, error-handling

hello python comunity,

How do I stop this from looping?

```
error33 = int(2)
    while error33 > 1:
        while True:
                try:
                    survivalrateforjuveniles = float(input("Please enter the survival rate for poomen"))##Float input is being used as
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a number between 0 and 1")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
```

Many Thanks

Comment: `error33` never changes? Then it won't stop.

Comment: do you even code?

Comment: A lots of things are wrong in this code. There is no need to cast an int to an int, `error33 = 2` is fine. Your condition is on `error33`, which is never modified, nor used at all. You have two `while` one inside the other, one of which never ends. Your loop only breaks if `survivalrateforjuveniles` is not a float at all, while you seem to be wanting it to break if `survivalrateforjuveniles` is not a float between 0 and 1.

Comment: well I am going to give you a pat on the back @Efferalgan

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works...

```
error33 = 2
while error33 > 1:
        while True:
                try:
                    survivalrateforjuveniles = float(input("Please enter the survival rate for poomen\n"))
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a number between 0 and 1")
                    continue
                else:
                    error33 = 0
                    break
```

I do not know exactly what you are doing... but I think I would use somehting similar to this:

```
error33 = 2
survivalrateforjuveniles = -1.0
while error33 > 1:
    while not (0 < survivalrateforjuveniles < 1):
        survivalrateforjuveniles = input("Please enter the survival rate for poomen\n")
        try:
            survivalrateforjuveniles = float(survivalrateforjuveniles)
        except ValueError:
            survivalrateforjuveniles = -1
        print("Please enter a number between 0 and 1")

    print('do what you want')
    error33 =0
```

Not so much different from your solution but you don't need the `break` and looks more robust. However, creating a function to read the `survivalrate...` and the other inputs (which I guess you have) would be much better since you would not use the same lines of code more than once (which is one of the basic practice to write good software).

Comment: And how do you know that `error33` should be changed in the `else`part?

Comment: @Matthias I just guessed that is the shape you would use in your code. At a certain point you have to change that error33 if you want to exit the loop. You can change it where you want. If that is relative to the fact that the input must be a float then I would change it after the `survivalrate...`